# Database-driven resource bundle in Spring

Tags: spring, resourcebundle

I have problem to make "database-driven resource bundle" work. In example below `TextDAO` is properly injected during application start, but when `messageSource` is accessed, a new `Messages` object is created - that's the point. How to make this work ?

```
<!-- message source -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="someapp.bundle.Messages" />
</bean>
```

*Messages.java*

```
@Component
public class Messages extends ListResourceBundle {

    @Autowired
    private TextDAO textDAO;

    public Messages() {
        log.debug("CONSTRUCTOR");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        // loading messages from DB
        List<Text> texts = textDAO.findAll();  // textDAO is null
        ...
    }
}
```

---

### RE-OPEN

As `Bozho` suggest i did my resource bundle as below, but have problem to dynamically reload it. I suppose that ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is for properties files, but maybe it is possible to work this, too.

```
public class DatabaseDrivenMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private final Map<String, Map<String, String>> properties = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    private TextDAO textDAO;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseDrivenMessageSource(TextDAO textDAO) {
        this.textDAO = textDAO;
        reload();
    }

    @Override
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
        String msg = getText(code, locale);
        MessageFormat result = createMessageFormat(msg, locale);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected String resolveCodeWithoutArguments(String code, Locale locale) {
        return getText(code, locale);
    }

    private String getText(String code, Locale locale) {
        Map<String, String> localized = properties.get(code);
        String textForCurrentLanguage = null;
        if (localized != null) {
            textForCurrentLanguage = localized.get(locale.getLanguage());
            if (textForCurrentLanguage == null) {
                textForCurrentLanguage = localized.get(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage());
            }
        }
        return textForCurrentLanguage != null ? textForCurrentLanguage : code;
    }

    public void reload() {
        properties.clear();
        properties.putAll(loadTexts());
    }

    protected Map<String, Map<String, String>> loadTexts() {
        log.debug("loadTexts");
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> m = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        List<Text> texts = textDAO.findAll();
        for(Text text: texts) {
            Map<String, String> v = new HashMap<String, String>();
            v.put("en", text.getEn());
            v.put("de", text.getDe());
            m.put(text.getKey(), v);
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is not quite clear - I don't get what, why, and how you are attempting to achieve it.

Comment: Hmm... I need resource bundle that gets messages from db. Thats clear i think. So, in that class i need to inject textDAO to access db, but i see that Messages object is recreated and injected textDAO lost... What is not clear ?

Comment: I did not understand where `Messages` comes into the picture. `basename` is `String`, so `value=someapp.bundle.Messages` is just a string value, not a spring bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`basename` is a string, so it is not a spring bean, and hence no injection there.

What you can try to do is to subclass `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and override some methods there (for example - `getMessage(..)`). The DAO should be injected in the subclass.

Comment: Oh yes, You are right. I make a terrible mistake with <f:loadBundle basename="myPackage.MessageResources" var="msg"/> from JSF, where basename may be a class.

Answer (score 2):

`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` creates an instance of the class named by the `basename` property.  This instance will not have any of its dependencies injected by Spring.  That's why the `textDAO` field in your `Messages` object is null.

[This Spring issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-364) has the source code for an example JDBC backed MessageSource, as an attachment, which you can use instead of `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but still relevant...
I am using Spring Cloud Config server with JDBC backend as resource bundle for i18n.
Zero code. Works awesome!