# Spring themes with hibernate by implementing Spring's ThemeSource class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, themes

Does anyone know how to use a custom ThemeSource in spring?  I have seen many examples on how to use themes with property files using ResourceBundleThemeSource.  Yet I have seen nothing on how to use hibernate to store vairous properties (such as a single css property) , read the properties with a custom ThemeSource and still be able to use the spring theme tags in the jsp.

I know I can create a controller and fetch these properties from the database with hibernate but I am more interested on knowing how to do this with Spring's ThemeSource implementation.

If anyone has any ideas or examples I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use themes in your web application, you must set up an implementation of the `org.springframework.ui.context.ThemeSource` interface. To use a custom ThemeSource implementation you can register a bean in the application context with the reserved name `themeSource`. The web application context automatically detects a bean with that name and uses it.

Here is the `ThemeSource` interface:

```
package org.springframework.ui.context;

public interface ThemeSource {
    Theme getTheme(String themeName);
}
```

The only dark horse here is a `Theme` type, which in fact is nothing more than:

```
package org.springframework.ui.context;

public interface Theme {
    String getName();
    MessageSource getMessageSource();
}
```

And in fact there is already a convenience implementation of `Theme` type from Spring => [SimpleTheme](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/context/support/SimpleTheme.html)

Notice that ThemeSource *expects* a Spring's [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/ui/context/support/SimpleTheme.html), which means that theme attributes that are stored in a database, in your case, would need to be "converted" to be used with a `MessageSource` interface.

You can either write your own `DatabaseDrivenMessageSource`, or just take it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498998/database-driven-resource-bundle-in-spring)

Now, having all these variables in place, here is a custom `DatabaseThemeSource` ( that will become a `themeSource` bean ):

```
public class DatabaseThemeSource implements ThemeSource {

    private YourThemeDao themeDao;

    public Theme getTheme( String themeName ) {

        if (themeName == null) { return null; }

        MessageSource messageSource = new DatabaseDrivenMessageSource( themeDao );

        theme = new SimpleTheme( themeName, messageSource );

        return theme;
    }

    // init your themeDao
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer that tolitius gives would work fine, but for real-world use I think that you need to incorporate some kind of caching.

Every request to your website is going to need your theme, but do you want every request to hit your database just to look up some colours? Themes usually aren't very large and don't change very often. So they're a good candidate for loading into memory and keeping them there. This is what we do with a site that we run, we keep about 50 themes in memory which are loaded from Hibernate on startup. It makes serving theme requests very quick.

The core class is, of course, your `DatabaseThemeSource` bean, which implements `ThemeSource`. If you have a cache library available such as Ehcache you could use that, but most people have fairly few themes and so a simple `Map` will do for that cache. We use something like this:

```
@Component("themeSource")
public class DatabaseThemeSource implements ThemeSource {

    @Autowired
    ThemeDAO themeDAO;

    private final Map<String, Theme> themeCache;


    public DatabaseThemeSource() {
        themeCache = new HashMap<String, Theme>();
    }

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.ui.context.ThemeSource#getTheme(java.lang.String)    
     */
    @Override
    public Theme getTheme(String themeName) {
        if (themeName == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Theme theme = themeCache.get(themeName);
        if (theme == null) {
            Theme theme = themeDAO.getTheme(themeName);
            if (theme != null) {
                MessageSource messageSource = new ThemeMessageSource(theme);
                theme = new SimpleTheme(themeName, messageSource);
                synchronized (this.themeCache) {
                    themeCache.put(themeName, theme);
                }
            }
        }
        return theme;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the cache of themes. This should be called whenever the theme is updated in the database.
     */
    public void clearCache() {
        synchronized (this.themeCache) {
            themeCache.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to implement a `MessageSource` that holds all the individual components of your theme. It's worth copying the individual elements of your theme from your Hibernate object into a dedicated `MessageSource` so that you don't have any problems with closed Hibernate sessions and LazyLoadingExceptions etc. It's also more efficient, because you can construct the necessary `MessageFormat` objects just once instead of having to do so on each request:

```
public class ThemeMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {

    private final Map<String, MessageFormat> messages;

    public ThemeMessageSource(Theme theme) {
        messages = new HashMap<String, MessageFormat>();
        messages.put("heading1", createMessageFormat(theme.getHeading1(), null));
        messages.put("heading2", createMessageFormat(theme.getHeading2(), null));
        messages.put("colour1", createMessageFormat(theme.getColour1(), null));
        messages.put("colour2", createMessageFormat(theme.getColour2(), null));
    }

    public ThemeMessageSource(Map<String, MessageFormat> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
        return messages.get(code);
    }

}
```

The end result is that it's quick. All your themes are kept in memory, and the elements of the themes are accessed rapidly though a simple `Map` lookup. We've been using this for a while and it works very well for us.

Comment: You must have answered right after I accepted the other answer.  This makes a lot of sense.  We went a diffeent direction and allow the end user to create their own themes.  A css file is created on save and stored in a db which is currently accessed with each request.  I haven't implemented a caching solution yet but plan to do so.  I appreciate your response but all I can do now is upvote your answer.