# How to associate the error messages table with the Spring Validation module

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-validator

We've been using messages resource bundle to display the error messages to the end user till now. However, recent design modifications require the error messages to be picked up from the error messages table in the database instead of from the messages.properties. Is it possible in the springs framework or we need to go with the custom implementation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely make your Resource Bundle a database table.  [This is a posting on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498998/database-driven-resource-bundle-in-spring) about the topic, which uses the [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html).