# implementing localization from database instead of properties file in springs

Tags: database, spring-mvc, localization, using

I am new to spring-mvc.
localization is working fine using properties file.But
I have translations in  the database(Key,Value_en,value_native)how to implement localizations from database.I saw the answers implementing abstractmessagesource,didn't get that.I didn't get that how to switch languages and configure in dispatcher servlet.

Help me little bit clear about to get the idea.

Comment: Following question has answer of your question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498998/database-driven-resource-bundle-in-spring

Answer (score 2):

A simple googlins took me to this article you should take a look at:

http://blog.javaforge.net/post/32188367580/database-driven-message-source-in-spring

The base idea is extending `AbstractMessageSource` with a couple of alternative classes: you choose which to use depending how your application grows (fixed languages vs fixed keys).