# JSF internalization

Tags: jsf, jpa, eclipselink

I read answers on JSF internalization implemented it, but still having issues. I want to implent internalization for JSF, I used Eclipse Link/JPA for my rny entities, I want to be able to load the value from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you already used 'message bundles' in jsf, where these are 'properties files'.

So, here's a solution for 'Database-driven bundles', you can try it: [Database-driven bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498998/database-driven-resource-bundle-in-spring)

Using spring on your jsf it's pretty easy, still if you need more help just let me know.

Comment: I don't like the idea to use Spring just for this case. Note that OP can do this using EJB's too or manually since it's an easy job.

Comment: That's not a problem, then you can do your own, here's an example of Pure Java + MySQL (could be any):  http://www.webreference.com/programming/Globalize-Web-Applications15_Java_ResourceBundles/index.html